# C program through mysql pull

Tags: mysql, sql, c, database-connection

I have this code to find the mean and standard deviation of some input values. But it's a static program. I want to pull this through a MySQL database and use it. Can you help me out?

```
int main[]
[
/* 2-dimensional array is used to store the height,lenght and the width attributes of the nose. indian
array represents
the indian data and the china array represents the chinese data */
/* Mean variable represents the mean values. The subscripts are used to identify indian and chinese
attributes */
float indian[MAX][3],china[MAX]
[3],mean_ih=0,mean_il=0,mean_iw=0,mean_ch=0,mean_cl=0,mean_cw=0;
/* Following float variables store the standard deviation values */
float sd_ih=0,sd_il=0,sd_iw=0,sd_ch=0,sd_cl=0,sd_cw=0;
int i,j;
float test_h,test_l,test_w;
```

/* POPULATING THE INDIAN DATABASE */

```
indian[i][j]=random[]/DIV;
```

/*POPULATING THE CHINESE DATABASE*/

```
china[i][j]=random[]/DIS;
```

Finding the MEAN of the Indian and the Chinese Data

```
mean_ih+=indian[i][0];
mean_il+=indian[i][1];
mean_iw+=indian[i][2];
mean_ch+=china[i][0];
mean_cl+=china[i][1];
mean_cw+=china[i][2];
mean_ih=mean_ih/MAX; mean_il=mean_il/MAX; mean_iw=mean_iw/MAX;
mean_ch=mean_ch/MAX; mean_cl=mean_cl/MAX; mean_cw=mean_cw/MAX;
```

To find the Standard Deviation of the entries

```
sd_ih+=pow[[indian[i][0]-mean_ih],2];
sd_il+=pow[[indian[i][1]-mean_il],2];
sd_iw+=pow[[indian[i][2]-mean_iw],2];
sd_ch+=pow[[china[i][0]-mean_ch],2];
sd_cl+=pow[[china[i][1]-mean_cl],2];
sd_cw+=pow[[china[i][2]-mean_cw],2];

sd_ih=sqrt[sd_ih/MAX]; sd_il=sqrt[sd_il/MAX]; sd_iw=sqrt[sd_iw/MAX];
sd_ch=sqrt[sd_ch/MAX]; sd_cl=sqrt[sd_cl/MAX]; sd_cw=sqrt[sd_cw/MAX];
```

Prompting the user to enter data to verify

printf [" \n ============================================================\n"];
printf[" \n Enter the Height \n"];
scanf[" %f",&test_h];
printf [" \n ============================================================\n"];
printf[" \n Enter the length \n"];
scanf["%f",&test_l];
printf [" \n ============================================================\n"];
printf[" \n Enter the width \n "];
scanf ["%f",&test_w];
printf [" \n ============================================================\n"];
if [[abs[mean_ih-test_h]

Comment: Why have all the braces and parentheses been changed to brackets in the code samles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to look at the mySQL C API documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html) for how to connect to a MySQL database through a C program.

For a tutorial, you can also take a look at [this](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/mysqlcapitutorial/).